# OnButtonPressed issue

Tags: c#, onbackpressed

Started with Xamarin Android yesterday and can't seem to figure out why the Back Button script(s) won't be called.

Searched and seen that a lot of people recommend something like this:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Back Button Pressed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

However this doesn't stop my phone or the android emulator from closing the app instantly.
Most of the things I have found about this thread I haven't managed to make work for some reason or they won't be called.

Thanks

**Update:**
Checked another project. It works 100% there with the same code as above. Not sure what makes it not work in my project

**Update**
Here is some of the code. I know it's terrible but I'm just messing around trying to learn as I'm a total newbie with Xamarin & Android - Feel free to give links on something I should read however!

```
namespace Workout_App {
[Activity(Label = "Workout App", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private List<Exercise> mItems, mItemsDay1;
    private ListView mListView;
    MyListViewAdapter adapter, adapter2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView); // myListView er navnet på objekte i AXML fila f.eks

        mItems = new List<Exercise>();
        mItemsDay1 = new List<Exercise>();
        mItems.Add(new Exercise() { Name = "Day 1"});
        mItems.Add(new Exercise() { Name = "Day 2"});
        mItems.Add(new Exercise() { Name = "Day 3"});

        mItemsDay1.Add(new Exercise() { Name = "Benkpress", Reps = "8x4", kg = 140});
        mItemsDay1.Add(new Exercise() { Name = "Lårpress", Reps = "8x4", kg = 58});
        mItemsDay1.Add(new Exercise() { Name = "BankPro", Reps = "8x4", kg = 22});

        adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);
        adapter2 = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItemsDay1);

        mListView.Adapter = adapter;
        mListView.ItemClick += mListView_ItemClick; // subscribes it, - to unsub
        mListView.ItemLongClick += mListView_ItemLongClick;

        // mListView.ItemClick += mListView_ItemClick2;

    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Back Button Pressed Detected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    void mListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        mListView.Adapter = adapter2;
    }
```

And this is the view

```
namespace Workout_App {
class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Exercise>
{
    public List<Exercise> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Exercise> items)
    {
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mItems.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Exercise this[int position]
    {
        get { return mItems[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if(row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false );
        }

        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
        txtName.Text = mItems[position].Name;

        TextView txtReps = row.FindViewById <TextView>(Resource.Id.txtReps);
        txtReps.Text = mItems[position].Reps;

        TextView txtKg = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtKg);
        if(mItems[position].kg > 0) { 
            txtKg.Text = mItems[position].kg + " kg";
        } else
        {
            txtKg.Text = "";
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to provide more information. is this code on a view for example. Read what you have written, have a quick think and add what you think is needed to help people help you.

Comment: @James Thanks, added some of the code. Would like to hide the code in spoilers to make it cleaner but it seemed that it would only hide line by line.

Comment: If your code base (that's not working) is just "throw away" code that you are playing with, might I suggest just starting from scratch since, in your own words, "I'm just messing around trying to learn as I'm a total newbie". Most likely you just changed something inadvertently.

Comment: It is basically my code written from scratch @Shai Cohen. However a lot of it is learned from a tutorial so I currently play around with too get more used too it and what I can do with it before I go on. It works 100%, it's just the Back Button Code that won't work.

Comment: I understand; it was worth a shot :) Maybe I'm missing it, or the displayed code does not include it, but where are you binding the button's click event? I see where you bind the events for mListView, but that's it.

Comment: You mean this part? https://pastebin.com/r1KxKbvt  If you mean the Back Button there isn't anything more too it :| Does it need to be binded? Thought it was already but I just override it's code